# In Node.js, why doesn't the request package perform basic authentication?

Tags: node.js, request

I have set up a test end point here:

https://9wi46s5jzc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test

For some baseline testing, I go to apitester.com and run two tests:

Firstly, a post request to: https://admin:password@9wi46s5jzc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test (correct credentials) gives me output of:

```
{"isBase64Encoded":false,"statusCode":401,"headers":{"x-powered-by":"Express","content-type":"text/html; charset=utf-8","content-length":"0","etag":"W/\"0-2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk\""},"body":""}
```

Secondly, a post request to: https://admin:BADPASSWORD@9wi46s5jzc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test (incorrect credentials) gives me output of:

```
{"message":"Unauthorized"}
```

So they're the baseline tests for what should happen.

When I run the following code:

```
const request = require('request');

const url = 'https://admin:password@9wi46s5jzc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test';
request.post(url, function(err, res, body) {
    console.log("body", body);
});
```

I get:

```
body {"message":"Unauthorized"}
```

Why is this happening?

According to the docs:

https://github.com/request/request

this is the way to do basic authentication.

So I'm expecting correct authorization but I'm not getting it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should try it using this :

```
        const proxyUrl = 'https://admin:password@9wi46s5jzc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test';
        const proxyRequest = request.defaults({ 'proxy': proxyUrl});
        const options = {
            url: '...',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + token // if this is how you handle auth and you already have the token
            }
        };
        proxyRequest .get(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                next(error); // if you're using Express
            }
                console.log("body", body);
            });
```

Comment: I don't quite understand this code. There's only one endpoint. What should 'url' be?